# How to insert NaN value to MariaDB using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, dataframe, mariadb

I have a dataframe like this and i want to insert it to MariaDB database using python:

```
      col1      col2       col3     col4
0      A         21         21       92
1      B         62         54       62
2      C         63         98       41
3      D         64         97       NaN
4      E         76         NaN      NaN
```

when I try to insert it to MariaDB i get an error saying:

```
mariadb.DataError: Invalid parameter type at row 5, column 3
```

In my table in MariaDB I specified to accept NULL values

How do I correct this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

df.where(pd.notnull(df), None)

my pandas version is higher than 0.13:
try this

```
             col1      col2       col3     col4
      0      A         21         21       92
      1      B         62         54       62
      2      C         63         98       41
      3      D         64         97       None
      4      E         76         None     None
```